# how do I listen to a data change in this custom bindingHandler?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a custom bindingHandler that works well when being clicked. It successfully changes the data point.. but it isnt being updated when another ui control changes the data

my html looks like this

```
<input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: publisher.my_check"> Checkbox
<div data-bind="slidebox: {label_on: 'ON', label_off: 'OFF', data: publisher.my_check }"></div>
```

my bindingHandler looks like this

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slidebox = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {


        var el = $(element),
            obj = valueAccessor();
        //add additional markup
        el.append($('<div>'));
        //set initial label
        el.find('div').text(el.hasClass('checked') ? obj.label_on : obj.label_off);
        //update the data point
        obj.data(el.hasClass('checked'));



        var updateHandler = function() {  
            console.log('i got clicked');   
            var el = $(element),
                obj = valueAccessor();
            el.toggleClass('checked').find('div').text(el.hasClass('checked') ? obj.label_on : obj.label_off);
            obj.data(el.hasClass('checked'));       

        };
        ko.utils.registerEventHandler(element, "click", updateHandler);

    },
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        console.log('i got updated');
    }
};
```

when clicking the div it changes the data point and the checkbox updates as expected.. but when clicking the checkbox, i don't see the 'i got updated' console message

Answer (score 1):

You needed to implement the update function. This gets called when any observable bound to on the data-bind attribute is updated. In this case `publisher.my_check`

```
ko.bindingHandlers.slidebox = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        ...
    },
    'update': function (element, valueAccessor) {
        var config = valueAccessor(),
            checked = ko.utils.unwrapObservable(config.data),
            $element = $(element).toggleClass('checked', checked);

        $element.find('div').text(checked ? config.label_on : config .label_off);           
    }
};
```

**EDIT**

Here's a fiddle with the working code http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/xrBSQ/

Hope this helps.

Comment: shouldnt my console log at least fire?

Comment: clarification: the log fires on startup but not when clicking checkbox

Comment: yes it should. I ran this in a jsfiddle (see edit) and it works fine. Without seeing your publisher.my_check code I can't help further.

Comment: wow.. that’s a gotcha.. just a console.log won't fire.. you were right i did need to implement the update code... but with ONLY a console.log there is NO logging going on

Comment: Not sure what's going on. This version has a console log and this fires every time. http://jsfiddle.net/xrBSQ/3/